# Loose pedals on Norco MTB

Tags: bottom-bracket, pedals

Just replaced my pedals on a very old Norco MTB.

I noticed while working on it that the whole pedal structure is wiggling from side to side is this normal?

I took the plastic caps off the base to see if it is an easy tightening fix, but not sure if tightening that bolt is the  way to correct the problem?

Comment: From the statement I am not sure if you mean the pedal or crank from pedal structure. Could you post a picture?

Comment: It's not clear exactly which parts you are referring to when you mention the "whole pedal structure" and the "base." The pedals are what you place your feet on. They are attached to the crank arms, which are each connected to the bottom bracket. The bottom bracket is the bearing assembly within the frame. You'll be able to get a better answer if you clarify your question. Also, there are a couple of different types of crank/bottom bracket combo. If you post a picture, that would help us to diagnose your problem.

Comment: The pedal shaft should be very rigidly attached to the crank arm, and the crank arm should be very rigidly attached to the crank shaft.  If there's any "play" it should only be in either the pedal bearings or the crankshaft bearings.  (If there is play where the crank arm attaches to the crank shaft then that's an "emergency" and needs to be remedied ASAP.)

Comment: A video will be very useful to see where is the problem exactly.

Comment: "Whole Pedal Structure" makes me think its the bottom bracket thats loose.  That would make the whole structure of the pedals wobbly.

Comment: It's pretty clearly the BB. Most newbs don't know how to refer to cranks correctly. Hence 'pedal-structure'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a loose bottom bracket (BB). It needs to be replaced.

You need to buy a new bottom bracket along with two special tools: A crank puller and a bottom-bracket tool.

If your current bottom-bracket is cup-and-cone style (it probably is), it can be removed with basic tools and elbow grease. If it's cartridge style, it can be removed with the BB tool.

Here are links to all three at Amazon:

[BB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DTIKQE)

[BB tool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A0AIAG)

[crank puller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001VS1M20)

Or, you could take the bike to your LBS and have them handle it. This is a common operation and probably wouldn't cost much.

BTW, the bolts that you see underneath the caps hold the cranks onto the bottom bracket spindle.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple different issues at work, but it's most likely that the bearings need to be re-greased and/or tightened. On some pedals, that little screw simply holds the pedal body together and the amount of grease in the bearing area will determine how tight the whole assembly holds together.

On the other hand, some pedals have a preload that adjusts how tight the assembly is, simply tightening this might solve your problem.

I would recommend tightening that bolt and see if the problem persists, if not good; if it does, then either replace the pedals or take them in to a shop to take a quick look.